Is it possible (how) to set the color mode of pdf to CMYK via reportlab?
I created a pdf using reportlab, but I opened it in RGB mode via AI。Why？ How can i do。
I want to create CMYK mode of pdf via reportlab. But i don't see where the parameters are set。
I have already used CMYK to draw PDF。
please help me。

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
